# Evaluation of elements in a list and then sorting them

Tags: evaluation, list-manipulation

This is probably a simple problem, but I'm having a lot of issues with it because I'm unfamiliar with *Mathematica* syntax.

I have a list

```
S = {{-1 + x + y}, {x^2 + y}, {x + 2y}}
```

I am trying to create a function `f` which returns a sorted list *after* substitution, I've tried variations of the following:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sort[Evaluate[Table[u, {u, S}]]];
```

but it simply returns the original list. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want because you don't tell us how your list of polynomials in x and y originated, nor do you tell us how want the final result to look. So I'll make some assumptions.

Assuming that you typed in the expression for `S`, there is no reason you can't make it a function.

```
S[x_, y_] := {{-1 + x + y}, {x^2 + y}, {x + 2 y}}
```

To see how to go on from here, try evaluating `S` for a particular pair of inputs

```
S[2, -2]
```

> {{-1}, {2}, {-2}}

Assuming that you want a simple list of sorted values as your final result, you would flatten the above list and then sort it.

```
Sort @ Flatten @ %
```

> {-2, -1, 2}

Nou you only have to define `f` to carry out what was done for one particular pair,

```
f[x_, y_] := Flatten @ Sort @ S[x, y]
f[2, -2]
```

> {-2, -1, 2}

Answer (score 3):

This is how you could do it:

```
S = {{-1 + x + y}, {x^2 + y}, {x + 2 y}}

(* ==> {{-1 + x + y}, {x^2 + y}, {x + 2 y}} *)

f[x1_, y1_] := Sort[S /. {x -> x1, y -> y1}];

f[1, 2]

(* ==> {{2}, {3}, {5}} *)

f[2, 1]

(* ==> {{2}, {4}, {5}} *)
```